# Passing empty arguments to sudo -i

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sudo

Here is an example bash script that I would like to run using `sudo -i`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "arg 1: $1"
echo "arg 2: $2"
```

When I run this command normally with one empty argument, it runs as expected:

```
$ /tmp/args.sh "" two
arg 1:
arg 2: two
```

With plain sudo, I get the expected result:

```
$ sudo /tmp/args.sh "" two
arg 1:
arg 2: two
```

However if I use `-i` (to pick up the user's shell and login scripts), suddenly the first argument disappears:

```
$ sudo -i /tmp/args.sh "" two
arg 1: two
arg 2:
```

And I cannot figure out any way to quote or escape the first, empty argument.

**Note**: I have figured out a workaround by writing `/tmp/args.sh "" two` to a file and then executing that with `sudo -i`, but I was wondering if there is any way to achieve this directly from the command line.

Comment: This seems like a bug in `sudo`, you should probably report it.

Comment: Bug report submitted: http://bugzilla.sudo.ws/show_bug.cgi?id=679

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me:

```
sudo -i bash -c '/tmp/args.sh "" two'
```

Comment: Another alternative if you need to pass env vars into your command is to escape the double quotes.

`sudo -i bash -c "/tmp/args.sh \"\" two"`

Answer (score 0):

Quote your empty double-quoted arguments with single quotes, like this:

```
$ sudo -i /tmp/args.sh '""' two
```

Comment: This doesn't work right. It gets literal quotes as the first argument, not an empty string.

Comment: Works for me. The outer quotes ensure that the `""` argument is passed to the user's shell executed due to the `-i` option, and then that shell interprets `""` as an empty argument.

Comment: This was one of my attempts. It printed `arg1: ""` instead of `arg1: `

Comment: I wrote a C program to print the arguments passed to it and called it exactly as I show in my answer. It prints its two command line arguments as strings, each surrounded by double quotes, like this: `printf("argv 1: \"%s\" argv 2: \"%s\"\n", argv[1], argv[2]);`. The result: `argv 1: "" argv 2: "two"`, which means the first argument contains no quotes but rather is the empty string, exactly as you requested.

Comment: Unfortunately my combination of bash/sudo (Ubuntu 14.04.1) gives me literal quotes using this command.

Comment: What's your OS, package versions? [mine](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/155592e79a13f5eb045235d9f73ce5a8)